# When was the first version of Hadoop released?

Tags: hadoop

When was the first version of Hadoop released to the public?  Any supporting links?

**Edit**

I should have been more clear - I'm asking this question because the Wikipedia article, the best source I could find on Hadoop, was not clear about when the program was first available to the public.

Comment: The question was closed as unlikely to help any future visitors.  It has since been useful to me.

Comment: The question was of interest to me aswell for a report; the website's [release page](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html#4+September%2C+2007%3A+release+0.14.1+available) has the earliest date as `4 September, 2007: release 0.14.1` stating "There are many other improvements". This would suggest there was a prior release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trivial method to find answer is to look at http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/releases.html based on which the earliest release is on September 4, 2007.

But if you want to look at how the page looked way back then here is the earliest scraped page available on wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20080123212822/http://hadoop.apache.org/core/releases.html